# Node.js express csrf

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Currently my code looks like this

```
var express      = require('express');
    ...
    ...


app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname, '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(validator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(connect.session({secret: "wewse43hgkvcret"}));
app.use(connect.csrf());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
    next();
});
```

And my view file looks like this

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/login">
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= token %>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
```

But on the csrf token im always getting the value of 'undefined'..

Comment: Try `res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();`

Comment: And later when it's actually set and forms are submitted etc, you should be able to get it with `req.session._csrf` inside your routes.